# Function responsible for calling the ServiceMain

Tags: c++, service

With the help of the following link I have created a simple Windows Service Code.
http://www.muukka.net/programming/service/Beeper%20Service.cpp

In this code I just want to know which function is responsible for calling the ServiceMain function ?

As per the Windows documentation they have said that the function StartServiceCtrlDispatcher is responsible for creating a service thread which in turn calls the ServiceMain function.
But sill I am unable to figure out which function is responsible for calling the ServiceMain function.

Thanks in advance,
Sid